# Using QGIS with R

Tags: qgis, r

I'm using QGIS 3.0.1 on Windows 10 64 bit.

I'm using R-3.4.4.

I'm interested to call R within QGIS and vice versa.

Is it possible? If not alternative.

Comment: What sort of integration of these applications are you looking for? This is a bit vague unless you can be more specific about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can call R scripts using the processing toolbox but you have to activate R in your preferences before accessing this functionnality.
*(Processing/Options/Providers/R Scripts/Activate in QGIS 2.18, i don't know for QGIS 3.0.1)*

Comment: You can call QGIS processing algorithms from R using [RQGIS](https://github.com/jannes-m/RQGIS). Though QGIS 3.x is not supported yet I think.

Comment: R is not supported in QGIS 3.x.x, at least I didn't understand how to add this feature there, so only 2.18